# How to Create an Azure KeyVault using Powershell with Policies

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I have created a Powershell module that represents my infrastructure as code.

Now I am trying to create a KeyVault.

In my function, I have a few parameters that I use to create the KeyVault.
This is how I tried it:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$SubscriptionName = "test",  
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$ResourceGroupName= "keyvault",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$KeyVaultName= "testKeyvault",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$ResourceLocation = "West Europe", 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$vN_ResourceGroupName= "vnet",  
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$privateEndpointName= "privEPKeyVault",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$vNetName= "vnet_$SubscriptionName",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$privateEndpointSubnetName = "SN_KeyVault",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$SubscriptionId = "SubscriptionId"

$virtualNetwork = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $vNetName -ResourceGroupName $vN_ResourceGroupName

$subnet = $virtualNetwork.Subnets | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $privateEndpointSubnetName}
$myNetworkResId = ($virtualNetwork).Subnets[0].Id
$ruleSet = New-AzKeyVaultNetworkRuleSetObject -DefaultAction Deny -Bypass AzureServices -IpAddressRange $subnet.AddressPrefix -VirtualNetworkResourceId $myNetworkResId
$tags = @{
    environment = "devtest"
    product = "cloudintegrated"
}

New-AzKeyVault -VaultName $KeyVaultName `
-ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
-Location $ResourceLocation `
-EnablePurgeProtection `
-SoftDeleteRetentionInDays 90 `
-PublicNetworkAccess Disabled `
-NetworkRuleSet $ruleSet `
-Tag $tags `
-SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId
```

I already have a virtual network set up in Azure that I can use to access the internet.

Some policies prevent it from being created.

Error Message:
Resource 'testKeyvault' was disallowed by policy. Policy identifiers:

"PD-EnforcePurgeProtectionEnabledForKeyVault",
"PD-EnforceSoftDeleteEnabledForKeyVault"

Answer (score 0):

> How to Create an Azure KeyVault using Powershell with Policies

If there is an `Azure Policy` in your `subscription` that denies the creation of a **Key Vault** without enabling `EnablePurgeProtection` and `EnableSoftDelete`.

If you attempt to create a `Key Vault` with `EnablePurgeProtection` and `EnableSoftDelete` using the below `PowerShell` command, it seems that `PurgeProtection` isn't being enabled, and it's not accepting any values like `true` or `false`.

**Powershell - New-AzKeyVault**

```
 New-AzKeyVault -VaultName "demovaulttestjg" -ResourceGroupName "Venkat" -Location "East US" -EnabledForDeployment -EnablePurgeProtection -SoftDeleteRetentionInDays 90 -PublicNetworkAccess Disabled  -SubscriptionId "<sub-ID"
```

**Azure CLI - az keyvault create**

```
 az keyvault create --location "East US" --name "thejvault" --resource-group "Venkat" --enable-purge-protection true  --public-network-access Enabled --retention-day 90
```

Alternatively, you can use a **CLI** command to create a `Key Vault` with `PurgeProtection` and `EnableSoftDelete` enabled, supporting the `purge-protection` parameter set to `true`.

I have the same policy in my `subscription`, but when I run the same `PowerShell` code, it's giving me the same error.

[image]

Reference:  [New-AzKeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/new-azkeyvault?view=azps-11.0.0) &  [az keyvault create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-create)